# What's the best technique for stacking the same multiplied object?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, google-material-design

I'm trying to create a material style illustration and I can't figure out how to multiply the object so that the edges are aligned perfectly. Even if I use Alt+Shift option the edges are bound to overlap strange.
So please help and I can clarify through examples if needed. English is not my main language.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the **Align Panel**? Copy and Paste in front?

Comment: The objects are aligned both horizontaly and verticaly centered but they still look like the example.  [Example](http://i.imgur.com/FnI8kUH.jpg)

Comment: Turn off **Align to Pixel Grid** on the Transform Panel.

Comment: Do you what to make a Honey bee's home? where the Hexagon are perfectly tiled?

Comment: Not quite. I'm trying to do a Google material style illustration.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, it looks like you want the Blend tool.

Start with a grouped shape, and make a copy of it. Transform the copy into what should be the last shape of your sequence.
Using the Blend tool, click on your first group, then your second group. 
[image]

With the Blend object still selected, double click on the Blend Tool to bring up the options for the spacing. As with any tool on the toolbar, you should be able to type in the settings.
[image]
Bonus points for changing the first Path inside the Blend Object!
[image]
Adobe Illustrator 2017

Answer (score 0):

Select the object then use the 'layers panel' drop-down and choose 'duplicate [path, compound path, or selection]'. The new copied object will keep the original position. I recommend working smart from the beginning by developing organized layers and groups, this way you can easily make reliable selections via the 'layers panel'.

Kind Regards,
Mark

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. The thing I'm trying to do is to multiply and resize the object in steps so that the final result looks like different sized sheets of paper.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the object by pressing alt key and please in the exact place without holding the Mouse (copying and placing should be in one click) then press Ctrl + D to make duplicates. Otherwise use transform/rotate tool and take first copy and define the distance and make duplicates